# Translate tab missing

Tags: webforms, i18n-l10n, 9

I am working on my first multilingual Drupal 9 website, and I face a challenge. I can't seem to get my contact webform elements translated. I am using Webform Version: 6.0.2.
I have enabled translation on the content type, and I can translate the title, body, menu item fields. But I can't figure out how to translate the actual labels & placeholders of the form elements. I have watched this video (D8), but I do not have the Translate tab that he is using: https://www.videodrupal.org/video/20180321/translating-webforms

I suspect that there is some module og configuration setting that I am missing, but I can't figure out what it is, so any help would be appreciated. My available tabs are the same as the ones on the screenshot from the Webform module page: https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-05-19/webfork-wizard-admin.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form labels are part of the webform's configuration, and their translation is therefore handled by the *Configuration Translation* (machine name: `config_translation`) module. When that module is enabled, it will add the Translate tab.

Answer (score 0):

you need to activate the configuration translation module. To activate it, log on to your site with an administrator account and go to: Extend: / admin / modules, and look for configuration translation. Select it and press the install button to activate, and then the translation tab for your site configuration will appear.

Comment: My English is bad sorry for some mistakes